# Placing multiple tooltips at the same position in a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, svg, tippyjs

A HTML page contains 2 SVG shapes, each with a tooltip (created with [Tippy](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/)).

How could I make the tooltips appear at the same position in the page (let's say in the red rectangle below - right side of the page)?

```js
tippy('#circle_1', {
  content: `That's a circle !`,
  arrow: false,
});

tippy('#rect_1', {
  content: 'Here is a rectangle !',
  arrow: false,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>

<svg width="250" height="250">
      <circle id="circle_1" cx="30" cy="45" r="25" />
      
      <rect id="rect_1" x="80" y="25" width="60" height="40" />
      
      <rect id="placeholder" x=150 y=25 width="100" height="50" fill-opacity="0" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Tippy documentation suggests that positioning of the tooltip is relative to the DOM node. So you can place the tooltip around the circle or the rectangle. That's basically the behavior and functionality. If you need to make tooltip visible at a fixed position, check out @Kristian answer below.

Comment: @AbrarHossain Yes jQuery would be better indeed. Still trying to make the text disappear when the text is not hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tooltip by definition is something that pops up where the cursor is.

If you need to set the popup text to show in other place, just use plain js/jquery

```js
$(".tooltip-elem").hover(function(){
  var tooltipText = $(this).data("tooltip");
  //console.log(tooltipText);
  $("#placeholder1").html( tooltipText );
});
$(".tooltip-elem").on("mouseleave", function(){
  $("#placeholder1").html( "" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg style="display: inline-block;" width="250" height="150">
      <circle class="tooltip-elem" id="circle_1" cx="30" cy="45" r="25" data-tooltip="That's a circle !" />
      
      <rect class="tooltip-elem" id="rect_1" x="80" y="25" width="60" height="40" data-tooltip="Here is a rectangle !" />
      
</svg>
      <div style="display: inline-block;" id="placeholder1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, jQuery seems to be the track to go. However, it does not behave like a tooltip: the text still appear when the cursor is out of the shapes.

Comment: @6PO0222 you can make the text disappear with ```mouseleave``` event. See updated answer